# Moving text box animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I'm designing a static HTML page. It has two input fields and a change button.

```
<form name="formTextBox" method="post">

    <span id="departImage"> 
        <img src="images/FlightImg.png"> 
    </span>

    <span class="spanInputOne" id="spanInputOneId">
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" 
            class="textBox" id="departTextBox" name="txtDpt" /> 
    </span>

    <input type="image" src="images/SwitchMode.png" 
        class="centerButton" id="changeButton" 
        onclick="change()" value="change" />

    <span id="arrveImage"> 
        <img src="images/FlightImgDown.png"> 
    </span>

    <span class="spanInputTwo" id="spanInputTwoId">
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" 
            class="textBox" id="arrivalTextBox" name="txtArr"/>
    </span>

</form>
```

What i wanted to do is, when clicking the change button, the value in text field should swap mean while the text box should move visually to another box position. so i've included css3 animation, javascript as follows

css3

```
.animation {
    position: relative;
    animation: swap .5s;
    -moz-animation:swap .5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:swap 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}


@-moz-keyframes swap /* Firefox */
{
    0%   {left:0%; top:0%;}
    100% {left:50%; top:0%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes swap /* Chrome and Safari */
{
    0%   {left:0%; top:0%;}
    100% {left:50%; top:0%;}
}


.animationOne {
   position: relative;
   animation: swapOne .5s;
   -moz-animation:swapOne .5s; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-animation:swapOne .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 
}

 @-moz-keyframes swapOne /* Firefox */
{
    0%   {right:0%; top:0%;}
    100% {right:48%; top:0%;}
}

 @-webkit-keyframes swapOne  /* Chrome and Safari */
{
    0%   {right:0%; top:0%;}
    100% {right:48%; top:0%;}
}
```

Javascript

```
function change() {

    var depart=document.getElementById("departTextBox").value;
    var arrive=document.getElementById("arrivalTextBox").value;

    $("span:eq(1)").addClass("animation");
    $("span:eq(3)").addClass("animationOne");

    document.formTextBox.txtDpt.value = arrive;
    document.formTextBox.txtArr.value = depart;   
}
```

The text boxes are animating well as expected. But text box values are disappeared after the animation is done. Could some one help me...

Comment: created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ln8Z/) for that one... for me it is working in Chrome... did you checked it in different browsers? is there anything else that does something with the values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above project was associated with `<form>, <input type="img">`

Since the text boxes, image button `<input type="image" src="images/SwitchMode.png">` were included in , it posts the values. So page refreshed, data wasn't available.

I've used the following code instead of `<input type="image" src="images/SwitchMode.png">` and it works.

```
 <img src="images/SwitchMode.png" alt="Change" 
    class="centerButton" id="changeButton" 
    onclick="change()" value="change" />
```